# CakePHP display updated table of data using ajax

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I'm having real trouble finding any documentation on this.

I have a page that displays a list of users, above this i can edit the users successfuly with ajax. After the update, i want the table below to be updated with the new information.

How do i go about doing this? I'm thinking i need some sort of view that displays the data in a table, and i want to get that view's contents and inject it into my page, but i can't seem to find out how?

Can anyone point me in the right direction please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put users table in div id like "Users" and do something like following in edit ajax success function call

```
$("#users").load("same_page_url #users");
```